# ViewPager inside service

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-input-method

I am creating a custom keyboard in android.Keyboard will also have custom emojis in it. I created separate xmls for all the emoji per page I wanted and now I want to inflate them in a popup when user click on smiley button.
Right now I am inflating an xml directly into the pop up window . It contains of images all of them are png format.Now if user clicks on any of the images it should get entered in edit text where user is typing.
How I will be able to set the clicked image in edit text??

Here is my code for keyboard service class

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener,EmoticonsGridAdapter.KeyClickListener {

private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;
private View popUpView;
private boolean caps = false;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private PopupWindow popupWindow;
private int keyboardHeight=500;
private static final int NO_OF_EMOTICONS = 100;
private Bitmap[] emoticons;
Button abc;
Context context;
@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    kv.invalidateAllKeys();
    context=this;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popUpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emoticons_popup, null);
    abc= (Button) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.btn_abc);
    abc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    return kv;
}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch(primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);

            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        case -10 :
            //View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.emoticons_popup, null );
           enablePopUpView();
            Log.d("smiley", "smiley pressed");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Smiley", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);
    }
}

private void playClick(int keyCode){
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch(keyCode){
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
    }
}


@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence text) {
}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {
}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {
}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {
}
private void enablePopUpView() {

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.map_pager);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    pager.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>country=new ArrayList<>();
    String[] countr=context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
    for(int i=0;i<countr.length;i++)
    {
        country.add(countr[i]);
    }
    for (short i = 1; i < NO_OF_EMOTICONS; i++) {
        paths.add(i + ".png");

    }



    // Creating a pop window for emoticons keyboard
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popUpView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            (int) keyboardHeight, false);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(kv, Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK, 0, 0);
    /*TextView backSpace = (TextView) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.back);
    backSpace.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0, 0, 0, 0, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
            content.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    });*/

    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
           // emoticonsCover.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void keyClickedIndex(String index) {

}
/**
 * Reading all emoticons in local cache
 */
```

}

Comment: did you found the solution if yes than guide me i have same problem thank you i advance :)

Comment: @MiteshJobanputra No I didn't find any solution for that and I have to shut that project as things were not possible to implement

Comment: ohk thank you for reply :)

Comment: how to implement horizontal scroll custom keyboard.plz help